# Typescript keyof where value has type

Tags: typescript, typing

I am trying to write a function in Typescript which takes:

- an object which has at least one member of type `X` (in this example: boolean)
- a key of the object which points to said value

  > (eg. `{someValue: true}` -> key="someValue")

Currently, my approach is as follows:

```
function myFunction<
    T extends Record<K, boolean>, // the type of the object
    K extends keyof T, // the key which points to X
>(
    obj: T,
    objKey: K,
) {
    const x: boolean = obj[objKey];
}
```

This works as long as I only need the object to be of type `T` and no additional types. However, I now need an object which implements both `T` (an object with a boolean member) and `AdditionalData`. However, if I replace `T extends Record<...>` with `T extends Record<...> & AdditionalData`, the type check of course fails.

The solution I came up with was to introduce another generic type `L`, which only includes data from `SomeInterface` and make `K` depend on that:

```
function myFunction<
    L extends Record<K, boolean>, // the type containing the boolean value
    K extends keyof L, // the key which points to X,
    T extends L & AdditionalData, // the type of the object
>(...) {}
```

However, this does not work either.

Is there any way to force the value pointed to by a key to be of a specific type?

EDIT: alternatively, is there a way to exclude a specific value from `keyof`? That way, I could just exclude any additional types from K...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't always reason very well about the type of generic parameter type fields. I'm not sure exactly what is causing it to not recognize the fact that `obj[objKey]` is a `boolean` but the simple workaround is to use an extra variable:

```
interface AdditionalData {
    a: number,
    b: string
}

function myFunction<
    T extends Record<K, boolean> & AdditionalData, // the type of the object
    K extends keyof T, // the key which points to X
>(
    obj: T,
    objKey: K,
) {
    const o : Record<K, boolean>= obj; // assignable
    const x: boolean = o[objKey]; // access works ok
}
```